# When should I create custom post types?

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development

When do I create the Custom Post Type, does it only need to be done once when the plugin is installed (so once), or do I need to do it each time in the constructor? Or does it not matter?

Answer (score 3):

Post types and taxonomies have to be registered on `'init'` for each request. Even the built-in post types are registered this way.

The *posts* for your post type are stored permanently in your data base.